# python text to hex and searching hex data or convert everything to binary

Tags: python, struct, hex, pack, data-conversion

Decided to do a complete remake of the question. Hexedit in its default settings displays hex in the center window and ansi text in the right window. The below is the current code:

```
patlst = [line.strip() for line in open(patch,'rb',1)] #Read Patch start
if alphex == 'h' :
    old = patlst[patlst.index('OLD:')+1] #get old data str
    new = patlst[patlst.index('NEW:')+1] #get new data str
    old = old.lower();old = ''.join(old.split())
    new = new.lower();new = ''.join(new.split())
pircwd = os.chdir('..'); pircwd = os.getcwd() ##DIR change
with open(tar, 'rb') as f:
    data = binascii.hexlify(f.read(160))
with open(tar+'BAK', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.replace(b'old',b'new'))
```

Original hexedit view unaltered:
[image: This is the original hexedit]

Desired result:

[image: This is the desired result]

Actual result:

[image]

I believe this requires the pack and unpack function to work properly? Or is there a better way all in all to do this?

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want to do. Can you post some sample input and output? (I think you might just be looking for the `repr` function...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from (ASCII-encoded) hex to binary, you can use `binascii.unhexlify()`.

Comment: I couldn't have got to this point without your reply. Hopefully with picture assistance someone (including you) may provide a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lost ALL my login info. And the registered email account is dead. Parks Banyon is the secret identity of Gary Washington. I'm going to repost the question in a different context, titled "python print data to stout in the format python sees. IE raw.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this particular question was looking at 3 problems and hopefully a single solution.  Apparently this is not the case. As such I will refer to the following stackoverflow question as a partial answer (Why does Python print unicode characters when the default encoding is ASCII?) and vote Dan Getz' reply as the workable solution. I will repost the problems as 3 individual questions and hope the answers do not conflict.